# Country border coordinates with GADM and R

Tags: r, gadm

I have loaded the `sp` library in R and the `rds` file for a specific country (see [here](http://www.gadm.org/country)), now how can I extract the list of coordinates from this object?

When I ask for the names of the object, the result is:

```
 [1] "OBJECTID"      "ID_0"          "ISO"           "NAME_ENGLISH"  "NAME_ISO"     
 [6] "NAME_FAO"      "NAME_LOCAL"    "NAME_OBSOLETE" "NAME_VARIANTS" "NAME_NONLATIN"
[11] "NAME_FRENCH"   "NAME_SPANISH"  "NAME_RUSSIAN"  "NAME_ARABIC"   "NAME_CHINESE" 
[16] "WASPARTOF"     "CONTAINS"      "SOVEREIGN"     "ISO2"          "WWW"          
[21] "FIPS"          "ISON"          "VALIDFR"       "VALIDTO"       "POP2000"      
[26] "SQKM"          "POPSQKM"       "UNREGION1"     "UNREGION2"     "DEVELOPING"   
[31] "CIS"           "Transition"    "OECD"          "WBREGION"      "WBINCOME"     
[36] "WBDEBT"        "WBOTHER"       "CEEAC"         "CEMAC"         "CEPLG"        
[41] "COMESA"        "EAC"           "ECOWAS"        "IGAD"          "IOC"          
[46] "MRU"           "SACU"          "UEMOA"         "UMA"           "PALOP"        
[51] "PARTA"         "CACM"          "EurAsEC"       "Agadir"        "SAARC"        
[56] "ASEAN"         "NAFTA"         "GCC"           "CSN"           "CARICOM"      
[61] "EU"            "CAN"           "ACP"           "Landlocked"    "AOSIS"        
[66] "SIDS"          "Islands"       "LDC"
```

Am I wrong to assume the list is among one of these?

Comment: see  [How to extract all the polygon coordinates from a SpatialPolygonsDataframe?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169599/how-to-extract-all-the-polygon-coordinates-from-a-spatialpolygonsdataframe)  or [R_Extracting coordinates from SpatialPolygonsDataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29803253/r-extracting-coordinates-from-spatialpolygonsdataframe)

Answer (score 2):

Sp spatial classes store information in slots, which have the prefix @. Coordinates should be inside the @coords slot for each polygon.

But if you are not familiar with sp class structures it is better to use the sf package, which uses simple geometries.

1) You can convert your sp object to an sf class:
New<-st_as_sf(Old)

2) You can retrieve the coordinates with:
CoordNew<-st_coordinates(New)

CoordNew is a matrix of x,y coordinates