# Extract SpPolygon or SpLine vertices in RSpatial

Tags: r

I aim to calculate the concave Hull from all the points of my database.

I'm trying to extract the vertices:
-of a SpPolygonsDataFrame 
-of a SpLinesDataFrame 
both are imported by readOGR()

I tried different methods but I'm only extracting centroids.

```
require(rgdal)
poly<- readOGR(".", "sample")
coordinates(as(as(poly, "SpatialLines"), "SpatialPoints"))
```

Comment: I found a package rangeMapper that extract only from polygons:line_points=vertices(line)
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘vertices’ for signature ‘"SpatialLinesDataFrame"’

Comment: Look  [Extract all the polygon coordinates from a SpatialPolygonsDataframe?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/207670)